# WordPress Custom Post Type with role and caps

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am developing real estate website using WordPress Custom Post Type, where user can publish, edit, delete their own post only. Here is my code but unable to achieve target...

```
function property_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Properties', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Property', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Properties information page.', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'region', 'city' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-home',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,

        'capability_type' => array("property", "properties"),
      'map_meta_cap' => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'property', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'property_post_type', 0 );

/****************************************
 * Add custom taxonomy for Property *
 ****************************************/

add_action('init', 'property_categories_register');


function property_categories_register() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                          => 'Category',
    'singular_name'                 => 'Property Category',
    'search_items'                  => 'Search Property Categories',
    'popular_items'                 => 'Popular Property Categories',
    'all_items'                     => 'All Properties Categories',
    'parent_item'                   => 'Parent Property Category',
    'edit_item'                     => 'Edit Property Category',
    'update_item'                   => 'Update Property Category',
    'add_new_item'                  => 'Add New Property Category',
    'new_item_name'                 => 'New Property Category',
    'separate_items_with_commas'    => 'Separate properties categories with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items'           => 'Add or remove properties categories',
    'choose_from_most_used'         => 'Choose from most used properties categories'
    );

$args = array(
    'label'                         => 'Property Categories',
    'labels'                        => $labels,
    'public'                        => false,
    'hierarchical'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'             => true,
    'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite'                       => array( 'slug' => 'property', 'with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),
    'query_var'                     => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'property_categories', 'property', $args );
}


add_action( 'init', 'property_post_type', 0 );
 add_role('seller', 'Seller', array(
    'publish_propety' => true,
 'edit_property' => true,
 'edit_others_property' => false,
 'delete_property' => true,
 'delete_others_property' => false,
 'read_private_property' => true,
 'edit_property' => true,
 'delete_property' => true,
 'read_property' => true,

 // more standard capabilities here
'read' => true,

));
if ( current_user_can('seller') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
    add_action('admin_init', 'allow_seller_uploads');
```

In users admin panel displaying all post...I want to user can publish, delete, edit only their own post only.

Attaching screenshot users admin panel dashboard..

[Screen shot of users admin dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meAA3.jpg)

Comment: Can you try to explain in deeper detail what exactly is the issue with your post type? Your admin users should be able to do all of the actions mentioned, publish, delete, and edit. If you hover the items in the back-end you should see edit and delete as options, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Just want user can publish, edit, delete their own post only. Hide other user posts from his admin dashboard..